# dependency:list exclude configuration not work?

Tags: java, maven

I want to exclude some jar in `dependency:list` only.
My configuration is(according to https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html) :

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>list</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>list</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeArtifactIds>someartifactids</excludeArtifactIds>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Then I run

```
mvn clean dependency:list -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dverbose -DappendOutput -DoutputFile=D:/dependency.txt
```

But the dependency still appears in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute plugins from cli, maven will use execution ID: `default-cli`.

Option #1 - change execution ID in your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-cli</id>
```

Option #2 - specify execution ID explicitly (works since [maven 3.3.1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5768))

```
mvn clean dependency:list@list
```